# Fetch data from SQL table comparing the name column using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I need to fetch value MySQL table by matching with name present inside array using PHP and MySQL. I am providing my array list below:

```
$rootArr=array(
    array('cat_id'=>'2',
          'cat_name'=>'Context Of Organization'),
    array('cat_id'=>'3',
          'cat_name'=>'Leadership'));
```

I have only the above given data and I need to compare with the below table.

db_folder:

```
id           name                        parent_id

 328         COO                          22

 329         Other Documents              328

 330         Forms & Templates            328

 331         SOPs                         328

 332         FAQs                         328  

 333         LEAD                          22

 334         Other Documents              333

 335         Forms & Templates           333

 336         SOPs                        333

 337         FAQs                        333
```

Here I need to compare with my array value with this table and fetch data accordingly. `'cat_name'=>'Context Of Organization'` equal to `COO` name column value from `db_folder` table similarly `'cat_name'=>'Leadership'` equal to `LEAD` name column value from `db_folder` table.

Here when array value will be `Context Of Organization` it will match with the name column value `COO` and fetch its child `ids and name` means for this record the additional value should be `name=COO,Other_Documents_id=329,Forms_id=330,sop_id=331,faq_id=332` and so on. My expected output is given below.

```
$rootArr=[
    {'cat_id':2,
     'cat_name':'Context Of Organization',
     'name':'COO',
     'Other_Documents_id':329,
     'Forms_id':330,
     'sop_id':331,
     'faq_id':332},
    {'cat_id':3,
     'cat_name':'Leadership',
     'name':'LEAD',
     'Other_Documents_id':334,
     'Forms_id':335,
     'sop_id':336,
     'faq_id':337}]
```

My final output array should be like above.

Comment: Is comparing of "LEAD" and "COO" is static ? Question is unclear  to me

Comment: @Purushottamzende : Yes those are static. Here there are some static comparsion.

Comment: If you exactly know what `cat_name` matches with `name` then add a new element in array and search with it

Comment: Pro tips for posting here: there's no need to start each question with "I need one help", and there's no need to finish each question with "Please help me". Readers know that you would like some help, but explicit mentions of it will sound like begging to a native English speaker. Keep it succinct, please.